# WebDAV return 401 - How to authenticate?

Tags: authentication, request, response, webdav, http-status-code-401

I have a problem with WebDAV. I have to get a list of files. I have this request:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<D:searchrequest xmlns:D = "DAV:">
<D:sql>
    SELECT "DAV:displayname" FROM "address" WHERE "DAV:ishidden" = false AND "DAV:isfolder" = false 
</D:sql>
</D:searchrequest>
```

Response:

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

I have user and password (who has access), but I don't know, how I can put this data to XML request.

Answer (score 2):

WebDAV uses an HTTP authentication.

So you put your credentials to an HTTP header, not to the WebDAV XML in the HTTP body.

The basic HTTP authentication works like:

- You get a `WWW-Authenticate` header from the server

  ```
  WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="server"
  ```
- You include the `Authorization` header to the next request. The value of the header is:

  ```
  Authorization: Basic username:password
  ```

  where the `username:password` is in Base-64 encoding.

  ```
  Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==
  ```

For details, see

- [Basic access authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) on Wikipedia
- [RFC 7235](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7235): Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Authentication